# Does TeamCity support silent installation?

Tags: teamcity

The question is self explanatory.

I'm looking to install TeamCity via a powershell script and being able to provide configuration such as database options etc via the command line.

I couldn't find any information in the [Installing and Configuring the TeamCity Server](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Installing+and+Configuring+the+TeamCity+Server#InstallingandConfiguringtheTeamCityServer-ConfiguringTeamCityServer) documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the related request in TeamCity issue tracker: [TW-15583](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-15583), please vote for it. General recommendations are described in the [comment](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-15583#comment=27-201766). Regarding database, you should configure \config\database.properties file to point to a new database.